# Why are chunks of images missing in IE 9? Isolated to "border-radius"

Tags: image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am currently redoing a site home page, and during testing, I am getting gaps of specific images missing in Internet Explorer 9. I have never seen that before.

Any idea what is causing this?

My account is new, so I cannot post a screen shot. Here is the link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlhi4.png

EDIT: I have fooled around with it some more, and it appears when I remove `border-radius: 5px;` the images display fine. Any way to get `border-radius` to display correctly in IE 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was being caused by my video card being overloaded. It was running at nearly 100% capacity doing something else, so it was causing issues rendering websites with Internet Explorer.